# How do you compare strings in Ant?

Tags: string, ant, build

In ant 1.6x the condition is never true despite app.get.method=download, why doesnt this work?

```
 <target name="-get-method">
    <condition property="do.download">
        <equals arg1="${app.get.method}" arg2="download" />
    </condition>  
    <echo message="${do.download}" />
  </target>
```

Comment: Did you run ant with `-d` (debugging) set?  It generates much output and may provide an indication of why things are not working as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce; it prints true as expected.  What does the echo of ${do.download} show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties in ant are global and immutable.
You have probably already set the do.download property somewhere else.

Trying printing the value of do.download BEFORE the condition element it will probably already be "false".